# Including a namespace in Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, cryptography, aes

I am looking to use the Aes Class from System.Security.Cryptography.

How do I set up the project so that I can create an Aes object?

Here is the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes.aspx

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a .Net class; you cannot use it in native C++.

Instead, use C# or C++/CLI.

Alternatively, use the native CAPI or CNG (Vista or later) interfaces instead in native C++.